# How do I get certain values from a list in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

If I have a list:

```
myList = ['car a', 5000, 'great value', 'car b', 8000, 'good value']
```

How can I do this in a `for` loop :  `(print(myList[0]) print(myList[3]))`

adding 3 till the end of the list.

I tried:

```
for carName in myList:
    carName = myList[0 + 3]> # I am stuck here
    print carName
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `print(*myList[::3])`

Answer (score 1):

You can slice your list using `[start:end:step]` notation, only supplying the *step* component:

```
myList = ['car a', 5000, 'great value', 'car b', 8000, 'good value']

for item in myList[::3]:
    print(item)

# car a
# car b
```

To avoid the expense of building a list for this purpose, you can use `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

for item in islice(myList, 0, None, 3):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could use a `for` loop to achieve that:

```
myList = ['car a', 5000, 'great value', 'car b', 8000, 'good value']

for carName in range(0, len(myList), 3):
    print(myList[carName])
```

Answer (score 0):

put the step size - 3

Syntax of For loop -

```
for i in range (start,stop,step):
```

Ex- Code to print even numbers

```
for i in range(0,11,2):
    print(i)
```

output-2,4,6,8,10

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is modulo % 3 == 0

```
myList = ['car a', 5000, 'great value', 'car b', 8000, 'good value']
```

This will print the first element and any multiple of three no matter how big the list is.

```
for i, x in enumerate(myList):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(myList[i])
```